# Multiple BLE connection is very slow in python (bleak)

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy

I try to connect two M5StickC to PC via BLE to upload their sensor data.

I wrote a data acquisition python script using bleak library.

The data acquisition rate is very slow when I connect 2 devices.

How to improve data acquisition rate on my script ?
I hope to get 20 data per second.

```
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakClient

address1 = "D8:A0:1D:55:EE:8A"
UUID1 = "beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5-ea07361b26a8"

address2 = "94:B9:7E:93:21:76"
UUID2 = "beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5-ea07361b26a2"

async def main():
    client1 = BleakClient(address1)
    client2 = BleakClient(address2)
    print(client1.address)
    print(client2.address)
    await client1.connect()
#    await client2.connect()
    while(True):                                     # very slow when comment out client2
        print(await client1.read_gatt_char(UUID1))
#        print(await client2.read_gatt_char(UUID2))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

edit:

Thank you for your comments.

I have updated my script following ukBaz's link.
Data upload rate is much improved, but I could get almost only single M5StickC data, the data from another one available sparsely...

I will ask this question to bleak maintainer.

```
from bleak import BleakClient
import asyncio

address1 = "D8:A0:1D:55:EE:8A"
UUID1 = "beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5-ea07361b26a8"

address2 = "94:B9:7E:93:21:76"
UUID2 = "beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5-ea07361b26a2"

def callback(sender, data):
    print(sender, data)

def run(addresses, UUIDs):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    tasks = asyncio.gather(*(connect_to_device(address, UUID) for address, UUID in zip(addresses, UUIDs)))
    loop.run_until_complete(tasks)

async def connect_to_device(address, UUID):
    print("starting", address, "loop")
    async with BleakClient(address, timeout=5.0) as client:
        print("connect to", address)
        while(True):
            try:
                print(await client.read_gatt_char(UUID))
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run([address1, address2], [UUID1, UUID2])
```

Comment: Your code looks very different to the two device example given by the library. https://github.com/hbldh/bleak/blob/master/examples/two_devices.py  Is there a reason you did not do it like the example?

Comment: I'm not sure why it's slow, that might be a question for the maintainers, but as general feedback, I think splitting this into two method calls, (one for each device) and then submitting them both as async tasks, could be a better approach. Here you have to wait for client1 to return before starting to read client2. The async system is not adding anything in your current setup whereas if there were two tasks they could each run at their own max rate.